# Use returned value from custom hook in react component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I'm working with react + firebase, i would want to use storage for some components, so i created a hook.

useStorage hook.

```
export const useStorage = (file: any) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const storageRef = ref(firebaseStorage, `upload/${file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        let percentage =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        setProgress(percentage);
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      },
      (error) => {
        setError(error.message);
      },
      async () => {
        // On Success
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log("File available at ", downloadURL);
          const url = downloadURL;
          const createdAt = timestamp();
          setUrl(url);
          setCreatedAt(createdAt);
        });
      }
    );
  }, [file]);

  return { url, createdAt, error, progress };
};
```

so, i want to pass the url returned from the hook to another component and use it.

```
// Form State
const [formState, setFormState] = useState<FormState>({
    drinkName: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    price: "",
    file: null,
  });

// Use url like `formState.file` = url, while trying to submit the form.
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(url);
    console.log(formState);
  };
```

Comment: So use it like `const {url} = useStorage()`

Comment: I have to pass a file as an argument sir